# getFilter() using BaseAdapter is throwing error

Tags: android, filter, baseadapter

I know there have posts on this topic but I couldn't found what's the problem in my code. After trying 2 days I am posting here. Here is my Adapter:

```
public class CustomerListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private static ArrayList<CustAccountObject> CustArrayList;

private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public CustomerListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustAccountObject> results) {
    CustArrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return CustArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return CustArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_list_format, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_custName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
        holder.txt_custEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_email);
        holder.txt_custId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_id);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_custName.setText(CustArrayList.get(position).name);
    holder.txt_custEmail.setText(CustArrayList.get(position).email1);
    holder.txt_custId.setText(CustArrayList.get(position).pkid.toString());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_custName;
    TextView txt_custEmail;
    TextView txt_custId;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    Filter filter = new Filter()
   {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for your list
            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = CustArrayList;
                results.count = CustArrayList.size();
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<CustAccountObject> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<CustAccountObject>();
                String filterString = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                String filterableString;

                for(int i=0; i<CustArrayList.size(); i++)
                {
                    filterableString = CustArrayList.get(i).toString();
                    if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
                        filterResultsData.add(CustArrayList.get(i));
                    }
                }            

                results.values = filterResultsData;
                results.count = filterResultsData.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
        {
            CustArrayList = (ArrayList<CustAccountObject>)filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
    }
```

Here is my Activity:

```
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
                             CustomerListActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

I have tried a debug but after coming to this `inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()` code App is crashing.

My logcat:

```
03-22 04:20:00.644: E/Trace(20950): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application asia.wavelet.android.application.MyApp: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
03-22 04:20:01.335: E/AndroidRuntime(20950):    ... 11 more
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at asia.wavelet.android.customer.CustomerListActivity$RetreiveCustomer.onPostExecute(CustomerListActivity.java:237)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at asia.wavelet.android.customer.CustomerListActivity$RetreiveCustomer.onPostExecute(CustomerListActivity.java:1)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-22 04:21:10.265: E/AndroidRuntime(20984):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My AsyncTask class:

```
    class RetreiveCustomer extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
      //display progress dialog.

 }
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        boolean fromLocal = true;
        if(isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.177:8080/ws/api/customer/5");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int response = con.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    json = readStream(con.getInputStream());
                    fromLocal = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        if(fromLocal) {
                Collection custCol = new Vector();
                custCol = custBean.query(null, null, null, CustAccountBean.NAME);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                json = gson.toJson(custCol);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return json;
}

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      String line = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        line = reader.readLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
          try {
            reader.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      }
    return line;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Collection custCol = new Vector();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type token = new TypeToken<Collection<CustAccountObject>>() {}.getType();
    custCol = gson.fromJson(result, token);
    //      List<CustAccountObject> customers = new ArrayList<CustAccountObject>(custCol);
    //
    //      lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //      inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer_search);
    //
    //      // Adding customers to listview
    //      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustAccountObject>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, R.id.name, customers);
    //      lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayList<CustAccountObject> cust_details = GetSearchResults(custCol);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomerListBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cust_details);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //      inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //
    //          @Override
    //          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    //              // When user changed the Text
    //                             CustomerListActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
    //          }
    //
    //          @Override
    //          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
    //                  int arg3) {
    //              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //          }
    //
    //          @Override
    //          public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    //              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //          }
    //      });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            CustAccountObject custObj = (CustAccountObject) adapter.getItem(position);
            customerEdit(custObj.pkid);
        }
    });
}

public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private ArrayList<CustAccountObject> GetSearchResults(Collection custCol){
    ArrayList<CustAccountObject> results = new ArrayList<CustAccountObject>();
    Vector vecResult = new Vector(custCol);
    CustAccountObject custObj = new CustAccountObject();
    for(int i=0; i<vecResult.size(); i++)
    {
        custObj = (CustAccountObject) vecResult.get(i);
        results.add(custObj);
    }
    return results;
}
}
```

Comment: @RajithaSiriwardena I have added my logcat

Comment: There's a    NullPointerException on the    onPostExecute on your     RetreiveCustomer     AsyncTask try fixing that

Comment: @RajithaSiriwardena but if I remove inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() then it's working fine. Actually I am receiving data from a remote server so used AsyncTask.

Comment: can u post your AsyncTask as well?

Comment: @RajithaSiriwardena added async